# Reassigning self attribute and getting AttributeError

Tags: python, class, attributeerror, self

This is my code:

```
class BasicPlan(object):
    
    def __init__(self, can_stream, can_download, has_SD, has_HD, has_UHD, num_of_devices, price):
        self.can_stream = can_stream
        self.can_download = can_download
        self.has_SD = has_SD
        self.has_HD = has_HD
        self.has_UHD = has_UHD
        self.num_of_devices = num_of_devices
        self.price = price

    def default(self):
        self.can_stream = True
        self.can_download = True
        self.has_SD = True
        self.has_HD = False
        self.has_UHD = False
        self.num_of_devices = 1
        self.price = "$8.99"
```

In the python shell, I create an object as follows:

```
test = BasicPlan('randomValue', 'randomValue', 'randomValue', 'randomValue', 'randomValue', 'randomValue', 'randomValue')
```

Then I try to apply the default method so I can reassign the self values:

```
test = test.default()
```

Now I try and print an attribute:

```
print(test.can_stream)
```

And I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print(test.can_stream)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'can_stream'
```

Comment: `test.default()` returns `None`. After the assignment `test` becomes `None`. Remove `test = `.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would make my comment a formal answer because I have extra suggestions.

First, `test.default()` returns `None`. After the assignment `test` becomes `None`. Remove `test =`.

Second, you can provide default values to the constructor, and there would be no need for the separate `default()` method:

```
def __init__(self, can_stream=True, can_download=True, has_SD=True, has_HD=False, has_UHD=False, num_of_devices=1, price="$8.99"):
    self.can_stream = can_stream
    self.can_download = can_download
    self.has_SD = has_SD
    self.has_HD = has_HD
    self.has_UHD = has_UHD
    self.num_of_devices = num_of_devices
    self.price = price

test = BasicPlan() # An object is created with the default values
```

Finally, do not store price as a string. Store it as the integer number of cents.